# What happens when I fail the dice roll for spellcasting?

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension

I am reading Mage 20 Aniversary edition and I am a little bit confused in what happens when you fail the dice roll for spellcasting (not enough successes as needed for the effect).

Let's say I want to use Life 3 in order to heal a person. I would need two successes as I am affecting another person. I have Arete 3 and throw 2, 3 and 9. One success. Not enough to affect another person. So what's next?

- The effect fails and I have to try again next round with 0 successes
  kept.
- I can continue casting the effect the next round keeping the
  previous round success (with +1 to difficult as per page 538 -in
  spanish edition-?).

If the case is that I keep no successes then I would need with so low Arete a ritual (extended action) for almost any effect. Am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes, in the circumstance you describe, the effect fails, and you'd have to start again.
2. At low levels of Arete, ritual magick will help a lot — it allows you to keep successes from round to round. However, you can also use specialized tools, Resonance, and Quintessence (as per page 503) to lower the difficulties and spend a Willpower to give you an automatic 1 success to start with.

Comment: Thanks. How do using rotes affect difficult? I have not find any reference to that in the rules.

Comment: @Averroes Turns out that's a house rule — I've been treating rotes as though they were "unique instruments," giving a -1 difficulty. Looks like that's not the case in M20.

Comment: I kinda remember reading the rotes' -1 diff too. So... was that removed from M20?